# Choose right options for completing sentences

Tags: word-choice, as

Fill in the blank with proper option.
We have these sentences : "He drove as ... as me" , "He was driving as ... as me"
1. quick
2. quickly

What are the correct options and why they are true ?

Comment: We try to avoid just giving answers to questions like this, unless you explain why it's confusing.  Is it difficult for you to understand using adjectives vs. adverbs?

Comment: Thank you Andrew again! I doubt in usage of adjective and adverb in this example.

Comment: Well, which word in the sentence does "quick/ly" modify?  The noun "he" or "me" or the verb "drive"?

Comment: Surely , verb "drive"  .

Comment: Yes, so the correct answer ought to be the adverb "quickly"?

Comment: Yes , But "as ... as" structure doesn't change anything ?

Comment: Aha.  See, that should have been in your question  :)  The short answer is "no, it doesn't change anything".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to ask which word in the sentence does "quick" modify?  The "as ... as" structure doesn't change anything since you can use an adverb or an adjective in the middle:

> He drinks as frequently as his brother.
>
> He is as [drunk as a skunk](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drunk_as_a_skunk).
>
> She walks as quickly as I do
>
> She is as quick as I am.

The more complicated answer is that, colloquially, certain adjectives can be used in place of their adverbs:

> Come as quick as you can!

However, I would avoid this, since some consider it "improper" English grammar.

Comment: And in second sentence we must look at main verb "driving" and therefore choose quickly . Am I right ?

Comment: I was confused because many times had heard  "Come as quick as you can!"

Comment: Yes, it's the same for both sentences.